# HTTP ERROR 500 - Guess missing PHP module, cPanel Apache

Tags: php, apache, http-error, php-curl

I am trying to move one server to another. So, I copy every php files from the old server to new server. Right now, I am getting an error of `HTTP ERROR 500`. Below are my error_log, my debug procedure and my assumption.

Here is what happen

- Old domain, executed `php myfile.php` - no error
- Old domain, open with browser `mydomain/myfile.php` - no error
- Localhost, open with browser `mydomain/myfile.php` - no error
- New domain, executed by `php myfile.php` - no error
- New domain, open with browser `mydomain/myfile.php` - ERROR `HTTP ERROR 500`

***Debug***

First, I check the permission

I see directory is 755 and my php file is 644. Guess this should be ok.

Then, I check the error log

```
[outbuy@outbuy brands]$ cat error_log 
[23-Apr-2018 14:51:11 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function LeanCloud\curl_init() in /home/outbuy/public_html/vendor/leancloud/leancloud-sdk/src/LeanCloud/Client.php:381
Stack trace:
#0 /home/outbuy/public_html/vendor/leancloud/leancloud-sdk/src/LeanCloud/Client.php(463): LeanCloud\Client::request('GET', '/classes/Brand', Array, NULL, Array, NULL)
#1 /home/outbuy/public_html/vendor/leancloud/leancloud-sdk/src/LeanCloud/Query.php(741): LeanCloud\Client::get('/classes/Brand', Array)
#2 /home/outbuy/public_html/brands/fetchBrands.php(14): LeanCloud\Query->find()
#3 {main}
  thrown in /home/outbuy/public_html/vendor/leancloud/leancloud-sdk/src/LeanCloud/Client.php on line 381
```

In Client.php:381, it is

```
$req = curl_init($url);
```

So, I double check the PHP module  (my php version is 5.6) and know that php-curl is installed already

```
[root@outbuy]# yum search php-curl
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, universal-hooks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * EA4: 110.4.45.120
 * cpanel-addons-production-feed: 110.4.45.120
 * base: ftp.cuhk.edu.hk
 * centosplus: ftp.cuhk.edu.hk
 * epel: ftp.cuhk.edu.hk
 * extras: ftp.cuhk.edu.hk
 * ius: hkg.mirror.rackspace.com
 * updates: ftp.cuhk.edu.hk
============================================ N/S matched: php-curl =============================================
ea-php54-php-curl.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications that need to interface with curl
ea-php55-php-curl.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications that need to interface with curl
ea-php56-php-curl.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications that need to interface with curl
ea-php70-php-curl.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications that need to interface with curl
ea-php71-php-curl.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications that need to interface with curl
ea-php72-php-curl.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications that need to interface with curl

  Name and summary matches only, use "search all" for everything.
[root@outbuy]# yum install ea-php56-php-curl.x86_64
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, universal-hooks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * EA4: 110.4.45.120
 * cpanel-addons-production-feed: 110.4.45.120
 * base: ftp.cuhk.edu.hk
 * centosplus: ftp.cuhk.edu.hk
 * epel: ftp.cuhk.edu.hk
 * extras: ftp.cuhk.edu.hk
 * ius: hkg.mirror.rackspace.com
 * updates: ftp.cuhk.edu.hk
Package ea-php56-php-curl-5.6.35-1.1.5.cpanel.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

Guess may be something wrong in here because for mbstring module, I use `rh-php56-php-mbstring.x86_6` a module starting with `rh` but here I only can see modules starting with `en`. Any suggestions?

Comment: Turn on in php.ini the option display startup errors.

Comment: PHP thinks `curl_init` is local to the `LeanCloud` namespace. putting `use curl_init;` might fix it. If LeanCloud isn't something you're developing, then I assume you have a PHP version mismatch.

Comment: @castis LeanCloud is the third-party sdk

Comment: instead of curl_init()  try \curl_init(). if it is a third party sdk, try contacting them.

Comment: @Gogol Still get the same error. It works in my old server. Guess I have some misconfiguration in my PHP settings?

Comment: Try making a simple php file just containing `<?php $ch = curl_init();?>`. if it throws error, then you might not have php curl installed and you will need to do `sudo apt-get install php5.6-curl` ( or similar ) and restart your server.

Comment: @Gogol You are right. Still get an error of ```Call to undefined function curl_init()``` by trying ```<?php $ch = curl_init();?>``` Seems php curl not installed correctly. But, did you see I tried to install php-curl ```yum install ea-php56-php-curl.x86_64``` ? Rarely I get ```Package ea-php56-php-curl-5.6.35-1.1.5.cpanel.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do```

Comment: Yepp I saw that. I am not that good with yum so I am not sure why this happens exactly. Try purging the php curl and reinstalling it and restarting the daemon.

Comment: @Gogol Ya. Trying to search whats wrong with curl_init module. Thanks for the help